# Get rid of warning "Expression Result Unused"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following few lines of code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url .... ];
NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection alloc];
[connection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

In the last line I get **"Expression Result Unused"** warning. Now, according to all the articles online I have read, this is the correct way to call a method, and the syntax is as advised to download a URL async. How to rewrite this code to fix the warning?

Comment: An example of the tutorial I am following is: http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Comment: You can replace last 2 lines with NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Comment: that just gives me a warning about res is unused :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact  that method `NSURLRequest initWithRequest…` return an object that you don't store.

If you don't need it, you should write:

```
(void)[connection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

On Xcode, you can use qualifier `__unused` to discard warning too:

```
__unused [connection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

to inform the compiler that you deliberately want to ignore the returned value.

Comment: this is really good, very useful for the general case, thanks!

Comment: And it is more portable to other C compilers than pragma.

Answer (score 4):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-value"
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url .... ];
NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection alloc];
[connection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

For a list of all the Clang Warnings you can suppress [take a look here](http://fuckingclangwarnings.com/)

Comment: Well I thought you wanted to suppress the warning. Didn't you?

Comment: no, i want to fix what is wrong with my code, surely clever ppl made the warning for a reason?

Comment: A good starting point would to understand the warning and if you can safely ignore or not.

Comment: agreed, at this point im too much of a noob to be allowed to ignore warnings

Comment: Well as you can see, the warning says that the method  `initWithRequest delegate` is returning something, which you are not using. Since you really don't need that, you can safely ignore the warning at this point. Anyway, you can use what @ChikabuZ provided which is a class method instead of an instance method

Answer (score 4):

You can use this line:

```
 [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

instead of:

```
NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection alloc];
[connection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: because you don't need instance variable of NSURLConnection just run it, the same with NSTimer

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last 2 lines with:

```
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The warning is useful because `alloc` can return a different object than `init` (for example, when you use `NSArray`, which employs [class cluster pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)).

In that case `connection` would be a reference to this "intermediate" object returned by `alloc` instead of a fully initialized instance returned by `init`.

Comment: this works too, but seems to be cheating the compiler instead of solving the problem?

Comment: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the last line to:

`connection = [connection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];`